# html input not accepting width on Safari

Tags: html, css

The input box is much larger than it should be on Safari when it is in a flex container. It works fine on Chrome but not safari.

You can see in this codepen that Safari thinks the input box goes much farther to the right if you put your cursor to the right of its box.
https://codepen.io/ryanjso/pen/mdVVrJz

`html`

```
<form>
  <textarea>
  </textarea>
  <input type='file'>
</form>
```

`css`

```
form {
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding-right: 20px;
  margin: 0 20px 0 20px;
  width: calc(100% - 60px);
  background-color: blue;
}

textarea {
  border: none;
  width: 85%;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  resize: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: auto;
  align-self: center;
  height: 20px;
  min-height: 20px;
  max-height: 100px;
  outline: none;
}

input {
  background-color: pink;
  width: 6%;
  max-width: 10px;
  min-width: 0;
  height: 85%;
  align-self: center;
  padding: 4px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  margin: 0 10px 0 0;
}

input:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to `display: flex`, try adding either of the following:

```
display: -webkit-inline-box

display: -webkit-flex
```